# Need to update JTable2 along with the JEditorPane on mouse click event on JTable1, all are in the same jframe

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jframe, jeditorpane

I am displaying 2 JTables and a JEditorPane in a JFrame. Both the Tables have different data. On double clicking the table2 i want to update table1 and the editor pane. I am able update the editor pane but not the table1. I tried the add e.getClickCount() == 2 for table1 , but its not working.

Basically when i click a row(which is the thread number) in Tabel2, the editorPane and table1 should update with the thread details. which looks like-

| 3105 | BOUNDARY_CORE_FCS      | 20101216 105754399 |    Entering XATransaction::getInstance

on doubleClick I am able to display that in the editorPane but not able to update it in the table. Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

The Code below is addMouseListener for table2-

```
JTable clsNewJTable = new JTable(new RCGUITableModel(arroData, arroHeaders));//... table2

JTable m_clsJTable = RCGUI.m_clsJTable2;// ... table 1

clsNewJTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){    
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){    
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2){   
            JTable clsNewJTable1 = (JTable)e.getSource(); // gets table 2                   
            int rowIndex = clsNewJTable1.getSelectedRow();  
            int colIndex = clsNewJTable1.getSelectedColumn();  
            clsNewJTable1.getSelectedRows();                    
            Object strCellValue = clsNewJTable1.getValueAt(rowIndex, colIndex);  
            doUpdateThreadsInTextArea(strCellValue); // this displays in the jeditorPane  

            //Should i create the new table1 here?and then update it or adding a new mouselistener to table1 is better?                 
            clsNewJTable1.setVisible(true);  
            }  
        }  
  });
```

Comment: Reformatted code; please revert if incorrect.

Comment: I 'vote against' more code and 'vote for' an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html).  Please remove all commented code lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

More code is a must. More interesting would be to see how exactly you are making the update of the components. Do you fire table data change for the changed table'd model, e.g. tablemodel.fireTableDataChanged()?

Hope this helps, Boro.